# How to combine an array with the same index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows

```
[{"2":[2]},{"9":[4,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,32,33,34,36,41]},{"2":[5,6,9]},{"7":[7,8]},{"9":[3]}]
```

is there any possible way to combine the value for the same index ?

Comment: your array has same keys but diff values,, for example first obj key:2=2, but later it's [5,6,9],, show us what format would you like to end with..

Comment: This question critically missing its exact desired result.  As a result, the answers below deliver results which have differing depth. Secondly, the failed coding attempt is also missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible decoding the json string and using array_reduce:

```
$arr = json_decode('[{"2":[2]},{"9":[4,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,32,33,34,36,41]},{"2":[5,6,9]},{"7":[7,8]},{"9":[3]}]');

$arr = array_reduce($arr, function ($carry, $item) {
    $key = key($item);

    if (isset($carry[$key])) {
        $carry[$key]->$key = array_merge($carry[$key]->$key, $item->$key);
    } else {
        $carry[$key] = $item;
    }

    return $carry;
});

echo json_encode(array_values($arr));
```

The result is:

> [{"2":[2,5,6,9]},{"9":[4,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,32,33,34,36,41,3]},{"7":[7,8]}]

Comment: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array, i have tried your solution but my array is not string.. it's an array ,

Comment: @Matei-Mihai : if I may say, you can even do  `sort($carry[$key]->$key, SORT_NUMERIC);` on line 7, and get array ordered as @Beshoy-Girgis did : both sweet ending though ^^

Comment: i did error myself, your solution works fine. thanks matei !!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json = '[{"2":[2]},{"9":[4,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,32,33,34,36,41]},{"2":[5,6,9]},{"7":[7,8]},{"9":[3]}]';
$multi_array = json_decode($json, true);
$result = []; 
foreach($multi_array as $arr)
{        
    foreach($arr as $k => $v)
    { 
        $temp = isset($result[$k]) ? $result[$k] : [];
        $result[$k] = array_merge($temp, $v);
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another option:

```
$old = json_decode('[{"2":[2]},{"9":[4,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,32,33,34,36,41]},{"2":[5,6,9]},{"7":[7,8]},{"9":[3]}]', true);

$new = [];
array_map(function ($arr) use (&$new) {
    $key = key($arr);

    $new[$key] = array_merge(current($arr), !empty($new[$key]) ? $new[$key] : []);
}, $old);

echo json_encode($new);
```

Output:

```
{"2":[5,6,9,2],"9":[3,4,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,32,33,34,36,41],"7":[7,8]}
```